# Animated unwind to the left

Tags: ios, swift

Tell me please whats can be wrong with this code?

It must animate unwind between controllers like source goes to the left and destination wait under it. But in fact it just blink and the destination is presented.

```
import UIKit

class UnwindFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        source.view.superview?.insertSubview(destination.view, aboveSubview: source.view)
        destination.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
                        self.source.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -self.source.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)
                       },
                       completion: { finished in
                        self.destination.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Done, find func insertSubview with belowSubview

```
override func perform() {
    source.view.superview?.insertSubview(destination.view, belowSubview: source.view)
    source.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: { self.source.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.source.view.frame.size.width, y: 0) },
                   completion: { finished in
                    self.destination.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                   })
}
```